# open a file with shared permission

Tags: python

How do I open a file with shared permission in python? There's another process already opens the file that my python script tries to write something to it. I am using open() but it doesn't seem to open the file with shared permission because I can't write anything to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The first process that requests exclusive access to a file is the one that determines whether or not other processes can also have access to the file. A process that comes along later (such as your script) has no say in it.

Comment: If the first process opens a file with shared permission, can I still use open() to write something to the file through python? I wonder if using open() and write something to a file with python will work if python isn't the only process using this file.